# for expressions filter doesn't filter anything

Tags: scala, scalacheck

This is a for comprehension (or for expressions) that unexpectedly doesn't work at all : the filter have no effect

Just trying to reduce the range of random int of two

Please help

```
import java.lang.Math.abs
import org.scalacheck._
import Arbitrary._

object Main extends App {
  lazy val minus2Int : Gen[Int] = for {
         int1 <- arbitrary[Int]
         if (abs(int1) < 2147483645)
      } yield int1
  println(minus2Int.sample)
  println(minus2Int.sample)
  println(minus2Int.sample)
}
```

In the book it is mention :

If the match succeeds, the variables in the pattern get bound to the corresponding parts of the element, just the way it is described in Chapter 15. But if the match fails, no MatchError is thrown. Instead, the element is simply discarded from the iteration.

Comment: You are filtering out int values which aren't very close to max int and min int, that is almost all of them, and you are surprised that 3 samples - which are generating values among those NOT filtered out are, well, not filtered out?

Comment: you right, that not a clever code BUT if you just run it a couple of time and you will see that the filter doesn't work (out range value appear soon ...)

Comment: Here for expressions filter from M.O book, no difference with this one, don't you think ? for {
    p <- persons              // a generator
    n = p.name                // a definition
    if (n startsWith "To")    // a filter
  } yield n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're code is trying to filter **out** 5 values. On the top, `2147483646` and `2147483647` (`Int.MaxValue`), and on the bottom, `-2147483646`, `-2147483647`, and `-2147483648` (`Int.MinValue`). So why does `-2147483648` (`Int.MinValue`) keep showing up?

It's because there is no `Int` value `+2147483648`. Since `abs(-2147483648)` can't be expressed as a positive value it actually returns the negative value, i.e. the same `Int.MinValue` value, which **is** less than `2147483645` so it  is **not** filtered out.